# Missing required parameters for [Route]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou tendo dificuldades para apontar a rota por causa dos dois parametros que ela possui.

```
Route::prefix('auction')->namespace('Auction')->name('auction.')->group(function() {
    Route::get('delegations/{auction}/view/{lot}', 'AuctionDelegatorsController@delegation')->name('delegations');
```

e a url que estou tentando apontar é:

```
@slot('url') {{route('auction.delegations', $auction, $lot)}} @endslot
```

O erro que ele retorna é o seguinte

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: auction.delegations] [URI: auction/delegations/{auction}/view/{lot}]
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, alguem poderia me ajudar a ver onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui concertar utilizando uma array associativa para os parametros.

```
{{route('auction.delegations',['auction'=> $auction,'lot' => $lot])}}
```

dessa maneira ele entendeu o caminho da rota com os dois parametros que eu enviava na minha rota: `{auction} {lot}` devem ser passados para a route como `['auction'=> $auction,'lot' => $lot]`